# The word for the vibe one gives off

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be the word for the vibe someone gives off... their mood.

He has a sour **__**.

Part of me wants to put attitude but I'm not talking about the attitude or the vibe really... I'm talking about the mood which he has as a person... almost his character.... like his inclination is to act this way. I know the word I just can't think of it... it starts with a "d" or an "e" I think...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> He has a sour **_**.

[Disposition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disposition):

> a person’s inherent qualities of mind and character:
>   *a sweet-natured girl of a placid disposition*

You can also consider [temperament](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/temperament) as well as [personality](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/personality).

Comment: Brilliant! That is exactly the word I was looking for!

Comment: Though the sort of person who says *vibe* might prefer *aura*. (I'm not such a person, so I agree with coleopterist).

Comment: Aura is good to but not exactly what I was looking for... Disposition is the word!

Answer (score 1):

'Demeanor' seems more descriptive of what another would pick up on. It refers to the way one carries themselves outwardly, whereas Disposition is more of a state of mind.